# Git mv, not picking up renamed files

Tags: git, cakephp, version-control

I've run a script which has renamed a lot of files folders and I want to git to know they are renamed rather than deleted.  The script was a CakePHP upgrade script. (./Console/cake upgrade all).

A git status shows they are deleted and added, which means I lose all the git history.  To fix this, I removed the old folder and added the new one, however there is still a few files that haven't been picked up.

The files/folders affected are:

```
test becomes Test
config becomes Config
models becomes Model
libs becomes Lib
vendors becomes Vendor
controllers becomes Controller
plugins becomes Plugin
views becomes View
```

This is what I did;

```
git rm -r --cached tests && git add -A Test 
git rm -r --cached config && git add -A Config 
git rm -r --cached models && git add -A Model
git rm -r --cached libs && git add -A Lib

#Views doesn't work too well
git rm -r --cached views
git add -A View

rm -r --cache controllers
git add -A Controller/
```

Pretty much everything worked, apart from the views folder.  Here is some of the output.  You can see some have been picked up as renames, but a lot are picked up as new files.
Is there any way I can get git to pick this up properly?

```
#   new file:   app/View/Clients/edit.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Clients/index.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Clients/show_spreadsheet.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/clients/spreadsheet_url.ctp -> app/View/Clients/spreadsheet_url.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Clients/view.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/clients/view_spreadsheet_queue.ctp -> app/View/Clients/view_spreadsheet_queue.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Contacts/add.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Contacts/edit.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Contacts/index.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Contacts/view.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dashboard/index.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dashboard/phone_lookup.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dockets/index.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dockets/select_for_invoicing.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dockets/select_for_payment.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Dockets/show_processed.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/dockets/view_job_for_date.ctp -> app/View/Dockets/view_job_for_date.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Elements/admin_crumb.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/elements/buttons.ctp -> app/View/Elements/buttons.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/elements/client_autocomplete.ctp -> app/View/Elements/client_autocomplete.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Elements/clients/incompatibility.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/elements/communication_log.ctp -> app/View/Elements/communication_log.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Elements/count_header.ctp
#   renamed:    app/views/elements/csv.ctp -> app/View/Elements/csv.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Elements/dashboard/equipment_list.ctp
#   new file:   app/View/Elements/dashboard/phone_lookup.ctp
```

...

Comment: Git does dynamic rename detection via "file similarity".  This works best if you do all the renaming as a separate commit, i.e., the *only* changes are "remove under old name, add under new name".  I can't tell from your question whether this was the case here, i.e., were there any other changes besides the file renaming?  Also, some file systems (Windows, Mac HFS) are case-insensitive which leads to, um, "issues"... :-)

Comment: My problem was the cake script did the renaming. For example it renamed config to Config. Therefore I can't do a git mv config Config. What I'm trying to achieve is to get git status to show all as renamed. This will mean a merge from another branch will pick up the changes. So there is actually no new files, they've just moved folders. For most of the part it works well. Just the view folder is fobarred

Comment: All `git mv` does is (more or less in one atomic swoop with backout if anything goes wrong, plus recursion on directories): `git rm --cached old_name; mv old_name new_name; git add new_name`.  So you can use the commands you used.  I'm guessing that the rename detection is failing because the script did not *only* rename files, it *also* changed some of them, sometimes hugely.

Comment: I think you're right, it did modify them. Would be good if git picked it up, but if it can't I'll just have to live with it

Comment: It may or may not be worth extra work.  I'll add an answer...

Comment: Is that a windows machine? or what OS are you on?

Comment: Everything is on a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

> A git status shows they are deleted and added, which means I lose all the git history.

Yes, you just need to commit that. No history is going to be lost.

Comment: But, if another branch has changed the same file, will it merge correctly? I think it won't

Comment: and I think it will :)

(do a backup before doing this kind of operation anyways)

Comment: The merge machinery uses the same rename-vs-modify detection as the status and diff commands.  So you *can* get mis-merges here.  If you can get the rename operations separated from file-modification operations, and later do your merges stepwise with these two steps, that will sidestep any such potential problems—so it may be worth some extra effort.

Comment: Well, there is only one way to prove it @AdamP :)... do it and tell us how it went.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be worth the extra effort I mentioned in comments, but, you could split this into two commits.  First, save this stuff, with `git stash` or a regular commit that you'll replace later.  Then, figure out what renames should happen, and do those yourself.  Here's an example...

```
$ mkdir /tmp/temp
$ cd /tmp/temp
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/temp/.git/
$ cat > .gitignore
*.o
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) da5da28] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
$ mkdir oldname
$ echo some contents > oldname/file; echo more contents >> oldname/file
$ echo "this file won't match" > oldname/trick
$ git add oldname; git commit -m pre-rename
[master 6be4d34] pre-rename
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 oldname/file
 create mode 100644 oldname/trick
```

Now we'll simulate the update script's actions...

```
$ mv oldname newname
$ echo "completely replace contents too" > newname/trick
$ git rm -r --cached oldname
rm 'oldname/file'
rm 'oldname/trick'
$ git add newname
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    oldname/file -> newname/file
#   new file:   newname/trick
#   deleted:    oldname/trick
#
$
```

Now we have a similar (but much simplified) situation.  Git can't tell that the directory was simply renamed, because the file `trick` also had its contents substantially replaced.

So let's save this and make it easier for git, by making two commits instead of one!

```
$ git checkout -b save && git commit -m 'save before splitting'
A   newname/file
A   newname/trick
D   oldname/file
D   oldname/trick
Switched to a new branch 'save'
[save 6935f96] save before splitting
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rename {oldname => newname}/file (100%)
 create mode 100644 newname/trick
 delete mode 100644 oldname/trick
$
```

Now we're ready to make this happen in two commits.  First let's recover the old state, on the branch we were on before switching to `save`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git mv oldname newname
$ git commit -m 'intermediate: rename files w/o modifications'
[master 7770d56] intermediate: rename files w/o modifications
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename {oldname => newname}/file (100%)
 rename {oldname => newname}/trick (100%)
$ git rm -r --cached .
rm '.gitignore'
rm 'newname/file'
rm 'newname/trick'
$ git checkout save -- .
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   newname/trick
#
$ git commit -m 'final: pick up scripted changes'
[master 8b28a2f] final: pick up scripted changes
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git branch -D save
Deleted branch save (was 6935f96).
```

Voila, we have everything done, but with an extra intermediate commit that makes the rename obvious.  Of course that intermediate commit might not be correct, testable, whatever (perhaps some files within it depend on the old names and *need* changes to match the new names).  So there are pluses and minuses to this method.  (You can do more work, maybe even test before making the intermediate commit and make minor changes that git can recognize as rename-and-modify ops, for instance.)